# NOT IN clause in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm trying like

```
select * from A where A.ID NOT IN (select id from B) (in sql)

sourcenew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Source.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);
destnew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Destination.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);
c= FOREACH destnew GENERATE ID;
D=FILTER sourcenew BY NOT ID (c.ID);
 org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <PATH> "D=FILTER "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
<EOF> 
"cat" ...
"clear" ...<EOF>
```

any help on this to resolve error, getting this on the execution of last line.

Comment: Think about grouping the 2 relations by ID and filtering out these having no match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN and FILTER the nulls

```
sourcenew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Source.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);
destnew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Destination.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);
c = FOREACH destnew GENERATE ID;
d = JOIN sourcenew BY ID LEFT OUTER,destnew by ID;
e = FILTER d by destnew.ID is null;
```

**NOTE**
I wrote a sample script with couple of test files and below is the working solution.In you case check to see if you are loading the data correctly from your files.

**test1.txt**

```
1   abc
2   def
3   ghi
4   jkl
5   mno
6   pqr
7   stu
8   vwx
1   abc
2   def
3   ghi
4   jkl
1   abc
2   def
3   ghi
1   abc
2   def
```

**test2.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (aid:int,name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'test2.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (bid:int);
C = JOIN A BY aid LEFT OUTER,B BY bid;
D = FILTER C BY bid is null;
DUMP D;
```

So in the above example records 5,6,7,8 should be in the result since those Ids are not in test2.txt.

[image: Output]

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias d. Backend error : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (1), 2nd :(2) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" ) @inquisitive_mind

Comment: And I even tried     d = FILTER sourcenew BY NOT (sourcenew.ID == c.ID);

Comment: @Vickyster, I've edited the answer and also included an example.Hope that helps.

Comment: @inquistive_mind it works like a Charm, thanks an ocean I have solved it by three intermediate steps :D and if you don't mind one more help..!

Comment: @inquistive_mind Thank you so much for the effort to help and resolve the issue, i will mark this as answer once I got enough reputations to up vote. Once again thank you..!