# Filter out records that exist in another table

Tags: apache-pig

Table A has 
100 records with Column1 in focus

Table B has 
10 records with Column1 in focus

So I have to always filter out the records in Table A based on the column1 in Table b

```
Table_B = foreach B generate flatten(TOTUPLE(SEN_NBR));

result = FILTER TABLE_A BY SEN_NBR NOT IN (Table_B);
```

any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and filter out the nulls.That will give only the records from Table A which are not in Table B

```
A = JOIN Table_A BY SEN_NBR LEFT OUTER,Table_B by SEN_NBR;
B = FILTER A by Table_B.SEN_NBR is null;
```

NOTE:I've answered a similar question with an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998767/not-in-clause-in-pig/42012316#42012316)

Comment: What if I want to use Table_B to filter many (say dozens) columns of Table_A? Does pig have an efficient way to do this? I don't want to write a left outer join for each of those columns.